# Regression Through Origin (RTO) with 2 variables?

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I am seeking a parametric expression of a RTO (regression through the origin) for a 2-variable system, that is, $Y = b_1 X_1 + b_2 X_2$. The OLS (ordinary least square) expression is [commonly known](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Reg2IV.html), but I am specifically interested in the RTO variant. Does anyone know the correct formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the materials you link to, you just set $a=0$ and proceed as normal. Using linear algebra, the Normal Equation $\hat{b}=(X^TX)^{−1}X^TY$ doesn't even change for RTO, although the structure of the contents of $X$ are different: $X=[X1,X2].$ This result, of course, generalizes to finite numbers of independent variables; likewise, all of the other standard results from OLS apply, with the stipulation that the intercept is 0.